# Why is `let foo = $HOME/bar` invalid?

Tags: vimscript, variables, environment-variables

Why is `let foo = $HOME` valid and `let foo = $HOME/bar` invalid in vimscript?

I have tried `let foo = "$HOME/bar"` but it is the equivalent of `foo = '$HOME/bar'` in shell script, `$HOME` is not expanded.

What is the canonical way to do the equivalent of
`foo = $HOME/bar` (valid in shell) in vimscript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VimScript is more of a programming language. So the following won't work just like in C.

> `let foo = $HOME/bar`

It's division.

> `let foo = "$HOME/bar"`

Inside quoted string only "backslashes" are pre-processed.

Therefore, you must do one of

1. concatenation: `let foo = $HOME..'/bar'`
2. printf: `let foo = printf('%s/bar', $HOME)`
3. expand: `let foo = expand('$HOME/bar')` or `let foo = expand('~/bar')`
4. substitute: `let foo = substitute('$HOME/bar', '$\(\w\+\)', '\=getenv(submatch(1))', 'g')`

... and so on

Note that `expand()` is also allowed to spawn the shell (so thing like `expand('$RANDOM')` could also work). Could be good or not.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use explicit string concatenation here, since `:let` wants an expression and the `/bar` looks like a division by a variable named "bar".

What you want here is:

```
let foo = $HOME . '/bar'
```

Note that `.` is the Vim operator for string concatenation here.

Comment: I noticed that Matt used `..` in their answer. I thought perhaps that was a typo, since I never knew of `..` before. However, looking at the documentation (`:h expr-..`), I see: "For String concatenation '..' is preferred, since '.' is ambiguous, it is also used for |Dict| member access and floating point numbers. When |vimscript-version| is 2 or higher, using '.' is not allowed.". TIL.

Comment: @JoL Yeah `..` is the "new" string concatenation operator. But `.` still works (and I'm guessing it will still be around for a long while), so I still tend to use it (in general and in my answers here) since it should still work in older versions of Vim as well.